# Always get CORS error when trying to fetch the data with api

Tags: jquery, ajax, api, cors

So when I do get request with ajax jquery with api I alwyas get the issue
    has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.Have tried with js fetch method and jquery method. Jquery method is preferred. Always get CORS error Have tried with dataType:"json" Have tried with dataType:"jsonp"

```
 $.ajax({
                url: "https://login.aupairint.com/api/v1/participant_showcases/au_pair_int.json",
                type: "GET",
                crossDomain: true,
                dataType: "jsonp",
                success: function (response) {
                    var resp = JSON.parse(response)
                    console.log(resp);
                },
                error: function (xhr, status) {
                    console.log("error");
                }
            });
```

Comment: The _server_ says "no". Changing data types on the client won't change anything on the "no". Just search for "CORS" here on SO.

Answer (score 0):

CORS is browser policy due to which you can't do ajax calls to other domains than your server. So if you running you code on localhost and try to do a ajax call to https://login.aupairint.com, it will get blocked by browser.

For solution, one is disabling CORS is browser settings. If there are multiple clients running this code all of them will have to disable it.

Second solution is to modify response headers. The API response header should support cross domain requests. In response header you should have "Access-Control-Allow-Origin: " then it would work

Comment: It's not localhost when trying to use same api on the staging server   https://aupairint918.a.wpstage.net/available-aupairs/ it works there